# Is there a polynomial with infinitely many terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am reading Hoffman and Kunze 4.2 and the definition of polynomial is the following

> **Definition:**  Let $F[x]$ be the subspace of $F^{\infty}$ spanned by the vectors $1,x,x^2,\dotsc$.  An element of $F[x]$ is called a *polynomial over $F$*.

Does that mean that $(0,1,2,3,4,5,\dotsc,n,\dotsc)$ is a polynomial  or in other words $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n $?

Comment: Span means all but finitely many coefficients are zero. So there is no polynomial with infinitely many terms.

Comment: @morrowmh Somehow I don't remember this  definition of span in infinite dimensional  vector space  can you give me some reference ?

Comment: The definition of span is the same regardless of the dimension. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span

Comment: @morrowmh ahaaa... now i understand

Comment: Another (and better) way of thinking about the span of a subset $T$ of a vector space $V$  is that it is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $T$. The definition in terms of linear combinations in the wikipedia page that @morrowmh quotes should be a theorem not a definition.

Comment: You need to trace back the definitions in Hoffman and Kunze.  They define the span of a set of vectors to be the intersection of all subspaces which contain that set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sum in algebra is *by definition* finite. In fact, addition is a binary operation, meaning that we only directly have to define expressions of the form $a_0 + a_1$. And provided that the addition so defined is associative, this is enough to extend to any finite sum:
$$
a_0 + \cdots + a_{n-1} + a_n := (a_0 + \cdots + a_{n-1}) + a_n.
$$

It's only by an abuse/extension of language that we ever speak of a "sum" of an infinite series, e.g. in calculus. As you know, this is actually a limit of partial sums
$$
\begin{align}
s_0 &= a_0 \\
s_1 &= a_0 + a_1 \\
s_2 &= a_0 + a_1 + a_ 2 \\
&\;\;\vdots \\
s_n &= a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + s_n
\end{align}
$$

A vector space, even if it's infinite dimensional, is an algebraic structure and so we only ever consider finite sums that are unambiguously defined, and for which there are no issues of convergence.

If/when we want to impose more structure to make a [topological vector space](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Topological_vector_space) such as a Hilbert space or more generally a [Banach space](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Banach_space), we have to describe exactly what our notion of *distance* is so that we can speak of convergence. Only then, can we consider infinite "sums", i.e. elements of the vector space with infinitely many nonzero terms such as in a power series ring.

Comment: We can consider such infinite sums in a strictly formal sense, too, without necessarily using the machinery of metric spaces.

Comment: Sure, as an inverse limit over system of quotients $F[x]/(x^m) \to F[x]/(x^n)$, $m \geq n$, then the [formal power series ring](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Formal_power_series) is 
$$
F[[x]] = \underleftarrow{\lim} F[x]/(x^n)
$$